# React Native receive error when spread operator is used in props assignment: "In this environment the target of assign must be an object

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, redux-thunk, spread-syntax

I'm currently using React with Redux and when I run the following:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const employees = _.map(state.employees, (val, uid) => {
    return { ...val, uid };
  });
```

I get the error stated above which seems to be targeting "...val" in the return method.  I'm basically trying to pull all the information I had from Firebase and returning it in the variable "employees."  Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the `typeof val` isn't an object (either an array[] or an object {}). You can just use `return {val, uid}`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input.  Let me try and get back to you on the results.  You might be on to something here!